# Drawing in MonoMac

Tags: c#, drawing, monomac

I am trying to draw some circles on a view in MonoMac, but I don't have a single idea where to start from.
Under .NET on Windows I'd do something like

```
Canvas canv =  new Canvas();
Ellipse ell = new Ellipse();
Canvas.SetLeft(ell, 5);
Canvas.SetTop(ell, 5);
canv.Children.Add(ell);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MonoMac works a little differently than WPF.  You have to do your drawing in the DrawRect() function of a derived class, like so:

```
public class MyDrawing : NSView
{
    public override void DrawRect (RectangleF dirtyRect)
    {
        var context = NSGraphicsContext.CurrentContext.GraphicsPort;
        context.SetStrokeColor (new CGColor(1.0, 0, 0)); // red
        context.SetLineWidth (1.0F);
        context.StrokeEllipseInRect (new RectangleF(5, 5, 10, 10));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
So I need to create an inherited class.
How do I 'put' it into the app.
Sorry for my ignorance, I am very new to MonoMac.

Comment: If you are using XIB's (which by your comment I am guessing you are), you would add [Register("MyDrawing")] at the top of your custom class, then in interface builder you would just place a plain NSView wherever you want, then change the class name in IB to "MyDrawing".  It should then all work!